# Synaptic package manager will not install

Tags: package-management

I get the following error when trying to install the synaptic package manager using:

```
$ sudo apt-get install synaptic. 

Reading package lists... 
Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done 
Package synaptic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'synaptic' has no installation candidate
```

Also tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Still get same message. Installed fine on my other host.

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: If you open _Software & Updates_, is "universe" enabled?

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt update`?

Comment: @Gunnar                                                                                                                                             Universe was not enabled. Have no idea how that happened. Enabled it, did an update and was able to install synaptic. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the `universe` repository.

In the command line:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Or using the Software Properties:

Open the Software Sources:

[image: Unity search Software Sources]

And tick "Community maintained Open Source software (universe)":

[image: Software Sources tick universe]